# What does "ship ship ship ship" mean as a comment on a webtoon?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms, slang

This is a brief description of an episode of a webtoon.

A boy, who seems to be very indifferent all about things around him.

And a girl (or a young woman), whose job is to take care of the boy.

(the two are never in any romantic relationship, but bussiness)

(she is maybe two to three years older than him)

The moment the boy was about to shoot some guys to kill them (maybe?), who attempt to harass the girl, she took away the gun he was holding and aiming at them.

and the girl just asked him out for a date, (maybe to check if he has an human emotion)

Then, this is the main question.

A person left a comment saying "ship ship ship ship"

What did he intend to say with this comment.

and this comment got a bunches of thumb-ups

As a non-native speaker, I don't get what the comment means, and why this comment is commendable.

The word ship is only reminiscent of an object floating in the seas

Is there anyone who can explain about this to me?

Comment: Can you give is a link to this tentoon? Of might be very specific to it's particular ausience, maybe referencing another story in the webtoons.

Comment: See [this slang definition](https://www.dictionary.com/e/word-of-the-day/ship-2018-02-14/#:~:text=%5B%20ship%20%5D,Examples).

Answer (score 1):

"Shipping" comes from "relationshipping". It is informal. It means that you would like to see a romantic relationship between two fictional characters.